# Bootstrap PHP file before `php -a`

Tags: php

Is there a way to run a bootstrap code at every start of PHP interactive shell? Something like this:

```
php --bootstrap "autoload.php" -a
```

Comment: include 'vendor/autoload.php';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`auto_append_file`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) directive for your cli configuration.

Example mine:

```
auto_prepend_file = /mnt/d/temp/boot.php
```

`boot.php` file:

```
<?php
$code = "aabbcc";
```

`php -a` test:

```
ariefbayu@DESKTOP-E76L6HH:/mnt/d/temp$ php -a
Interactive mode enabled

php > echo $code;
aabbcc
php >
```